# Issue with SSRS Sub Report while passing GUID as Parameter

Tags: ssrs-2012

When trying to send the GUID parameter in the SSRS Sub Report
When trying to invoke sub report, it is throwing following error,
Query execution failed for dataset “xyz” Conversion Failed When converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier

Already Tried Option: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b3690c51-32fd-42cf-8c40-78407b9c4cc0/failed-to-convert-parameter-value-from-string-to-guid?forum=sqlreportingservices
Which suggest following
DECLARE @guidID uniqueidentifier
SELECT @guidID = CAST(@V_V_1_VarChar_TransactionMSUI as uniqueidentifier)
EXEC G_S_GetTransactionAccountRolesAndCustomers @guidID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As RDL did not understand the GUID, so I would like to suggest to changes this GUID to string at RDL side, In your SP get this as string only and while comparing it with table data, convert it into GUID.

Please reply me if this did not work.